# In scala, how to find invocation of subroutines defined in a function

Tags: scala, reflection

Assuming that I have a function/method:

```
class A {

def function() = {
   subroutine("A")
   ...
   subroutine("B")
   ...
   subroutine("C")
}

def subroutine(a: String) = { ... }

}
```

Is it possible to use Scala reflective programming to find all 3 invocations of subroutine(a: String) in function(), without calling function() itself? (Which will potentially take a long process)

Comment: What's the use-case? Do you just want to find the static occurrences? E.g what happens if one is called multiple times in a loop or not at all because of a condition?

Comment: Hi Paul: Yes I just want to find the static occurrences (compile-time universe theoretically can handle that) regardless of whether they are actually called or not.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Is it a tool to analyse scala code, or for some control flow while the program is running?

Comment: Its for a control flow, of a library, in which a scala function can be 'interpolated' as API parameters, invocation of each of this function requires some initialization process that should be identified before main API

Answer (score 1):

You can try to resolve this problem in general without introspection via some cool functional tools.

Let's use [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) it has special typeclass [`Arrow`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day15) which is abstraction of `Function`.
It allows to do pretty much anything that you usualy do with functions.
So, lets define special type which contains not only function, but call hierarchy in some readable way.

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.tree._
import scalaz.std.function._
import scalaz.syntax.arrow._
import scalaz.std.string._

case class Subroutine[-A, +B](hier: Seq[Tree[String]], run: A => B) {
  def named(name: String) = Subroutine(Seq(name.node(hier: _*)), run)

  def printHier = hier.map(_.drawTree).mkString("\n" + "V" * 15 + "\n")
}

object Subroutine {
  def named[A, B](tag: String)(run: A => B) = Subroutine(Seq(tag.leaf), run)

  implicit def anon[A, B](run: A => B) = Subroutine(Seq.empty, run)

  implicit object subroutineArrow extends Arrow[Subroutine] {
    def arr[A, B](f: (A) => B): Subroutine[A, B] = anon(f)

    def first[A, B, C](f: Subroutine[A, B]): Subroutine[(A, C), (B, C)] =
      Subroutine(f.hier, f.run.first[C]).named("$1->")

    override def second[A, B, C](f: Subroutine[A, B]): Subroutine[(C, A), (C, B)] =
      Subroutine(f.hier, f.run.second[C]).named("$2->")

    def id[A]: Subroutine[A, A] = anon(identity)

    def compose[A, B, C](f: Subroutine[B, C], g: Subroutine[A, B]): Subroutine[A, C] =
      Subroutine(g.hier ++ f.hier, f.run compose g.run)
  }
}
```

Now lets define some subroutines

```
import Subroutine._

val square = { (x: Double) => x * x } named "square"
val sqrt = math.sqrt _ named "sqrt"

val sum = Subroutine.named[(Double, Double), Double]("sum"){ case (x, y) => x + y}

val abs = ((square *** square) >>> sum >>> sqrt) named "abs"
```

from here you can verify that

```
abs.run(3,4)
```

giving result `5.0`

while

```
abs.printHier
```

giving interesting calling order like

```
"abs"
|
+- "$1->"
|  |
|  `- "square"
|
+- "$2->"
|  |
|  `- "square"
|
+- "sum"
|
`- "sqrt"
```

or even define

```
def pack22[X] = Subroutine.anon[(X, X, X, X), ((X, X), (X, X))] { case (a, b, c, d) => ((a, b), (c, d)) }

val abs4 = ((abs *** abs) >>> abs <<< pack22[Double]) named "abs4"
```

and evaluate

```
abs4.run(15, 20, 36, 48)
```

and

```
abs4.printHier
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to this amazing library! But unfortunately in my case function "abs" is a complex algorithm of thousands lines of code written in plain scala, and may be expanded by different people. So the solution can only justify its cost for much smaller scale.